# Is there a Japanese universal verb for "imply"?

Tags: words, semantics

Very often I want to express an idea of "X is implied in Y", e.g.

> Is "I" implied in the following sentence?

Google translate tool offers the following:

> 「私」は次の文で暗示されていますか？

Three-part question:

1. Does Google translation correctly expresses the idea?
2. Is it possible to use the verb 仄めかす in this case?

> 「私」は次の文で仄めかされていますか？

3. Is there a better way to express "Is X implied in Y"?

Comment: Have you tried searching the definitions in a J-J dictionary? See https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/205105/meaning/m0u/「 それとなく言葉や態度に表して示す。」(="To indirectly display expressions and attitudes.")　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/8472/meaning/m0u/%E6%9A%97%E7%A4%BA/　「物事を明確には示さず、手がかりを与えてそれとなく知らせること。また、そのような手がかり。」(="Indirectly making things known by giving clues, without clearly showing it. Or such type of clues.").

Comment: 「匂{にお}わす」ではどうですか。

Comment: ^ 文法の説明に使う表現を探してると思ったんですけど・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

１． I don't think 「『私』は次の文で暗示されていますか？」 is a very good translation for "Is 'I' implied in the following sentence?".

２． 「『私』は次の文で仄めかされていますか？」 doesn't sound too good to me, either.

３． How about using 「[含意]{がんい}する/される」?

> 「YにXは含意され（てい）ますか？」 "Is X implied in Y?"
>   「YはXを含意し（てい）ますか？」 "Does Y imply X?"

---

> Is there a Japanese universal verb for “imply”?

I don't think 含意する would be a universal word for "imply".
I just think 含意する would fit your example here.

Comment: I will note that 含意 seems academic, but if I may ask about your examples, why did you make the first sentence pattern causative?

Comment: @BigRigz, Sorry, I don't know which sentence you're referring to. 「含意され(てい)ますか」 doesn't contain causative. 含意される is the passive form of 含意する.

Comment: Oh sorry, I confused する. My point it why not します? YはXを含意します has it, but the other one does not. Does it has something to do with tenses?

Comment: @BigRigz, Sorry I still don't know what you mean. As you may know, 含意する/します is a transitive verb, and 含意される/されます is its passive form. 「YはXを含意しますか？」 "Does Y imply X?" is an active voice sentence, and 「YにXは含意されますか？」 "Is X implied in Y?" is its passive voice equivalent. 含意されます doesn't contain します because it's passive.

Comment: That is my question: why does YにXは含意しますか not work?

Comment: @BigRigz It doesn't work because 含意する is not an intransitive verb.  "YにXは含意します(か)" ←  What do you think it means? "

Comment: ...I must have forgotten some things, but that still does not make sense. I see I should review passive verbs.

Comment: @BigRigz うーん‥どこがわかんないのかがわかんないですが…  How about considering 「海水が塩分を含む。Seawater contains salt.」 and 「海水に塩分が含まれる。Salt is contained in seawater.」? 「海水に塩分が含む。」 doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: I know this is a late response, but the first one makes much more sense based on the English translation. I will review verbs over the winter break for me and I will see if the context makes more sense after that.